# How can I dry this Rails Controller Action further

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dry

Our application uses a number of environments so we can experiment with settings without breaking things. In a typical controller action, I have something like this:

```
def some_action    
  ...
  if @foo.development_mode == 'Production'           
    @settings = SomeHelper::Production.lan(bar)
  elsif @foo.development_mode == 'Beta'
    @settings = SomeHelper::Beta.lan(nas)
  elsif @foo.development_mode == 'Experimental'
    @settings = SomeHelper::Experimental.lan(nas)
  end
  ...
 end
```

Since we have dozens of these, I figured I could try and dry things up with something like this:

```
 @settings = "SomeHelper::#{@foo.development_mode}.lan(bar)"
```

Which obviously doesn't work - I just get:

```
 "NasHelper::Production.lan(bar)"
```

How can I reduce this down or do I have to stick with what I've got??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is that you're ending up with a String rather than the object, you can use `String.constantize` (Rails only, with standard Ruby you'd have to implement this; it uses Object.const_get(String))

Another option would be `.const_get` (e.g. `Object.const_get(x)` where x is your string), you it doesn't, on its own, nest correctly, so you would have to split at "::", etc.

Also, there's the option of using `eval` to evaluate the String. 
But note: `eval` should be used with great care (it's powerful), or not at all.

**Edit:**

This means that instead of:

```
 @settings = "SomeHelper::#{@foo.development_mode}.lan(bar)"
```

You could run:

```
 @settings = "SomeHelper::#{@foo.development_mode}".constantize.lan(bar)
```

**Useful Sources:**

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/183112

http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/eval_isnt_quite_pure_evil

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `@settings` receives the result of the method `SomeHelper::Production.lan(bar)`; in the second, `@settings` just gets a string.  You *could* use the [`send` method of `Object` linked here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to fire the method, or `eval`, but this wouldn't be my first choice.

It looks like you might be reinventing a wheel -- Rails already has the concept of "environments" pretty well wired into everything -- they are defined in `app/config/environments`.  You set the environment when you launch the server, and can test like `Rails.env.production?`.  To create new environments, just copy the existing environment file of the one closest to the new one, e.g. copy `production.rb` to `beta.rb` and edit as necessary, then test `Rails.env.beta?`, for example.

But this still leaves you testing which one all over the place.  You can add to the `config` hash (e.g. `config.some_helper.lan = 'bar'`), which value you can assign to `@settings` directly.  You have to make sure there's either a default or it's defined in all environments, but I think this is probably the right approach ... not knowing exactly what you aim to accomplish.

Comment: We're aware of environments but these actions are for devices that are connected which get different settings depending on their parent environment. A bit confusing I know.